# linux shell script math operation

Tags: linux, shell

Here is my code and output, and expect output 4 (=1*2+2), and wondering what is wrong? Thanks.

```
Foo=1
Goo=2
Zoo=`$Foo*2+$Goo`
Zoo=`expr $Foo*2+$Goo`
echo $Zoo

output,
1*2+2
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: `Zoo=\`$Foo*2+$Goo\`` is not a valid shell arithmetic operation. You are presumably getting an error from that line. Showing that error (and any others you get) and that you tried to understand the problem is generally a good idea.

Comment: Consider the number of arguments passed to expr.  `expr 1 * 2 + 2` is very different than `expr 1*2+2`  (whitespace matters)

Comment: @WilliamPursell, thanks and I do not have whitespace in my code, and wondering if you find anything wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: Lin Ma, the problem is that you *need* whitespace in your code, if you're going to use `expr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Read man bash, Arithmetic Expansion:

```
Foo=1
Goo=2
Zoo=$(($Foo*2+$Goo))
echo $Zoo 
4
```

Comment: Thanks tink, your code works, vote up and what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Several things. Line 3 of your code should give you an error "Unknown command". Had that worked line 4 would simply overwrite the assignment in line 3. For the variant in line 4 to actually work the way you expected the format would be Zoo=$( expr $Foo \* 2 \+ $Goo )

Comment: Darn ... the backslash in front of the asterisk is missing, and i can't edit the previous response anymore.  @LinMa ...

Comment: Was a pleasure. :)